# On Android, how to keep running a thread till it's stopped by the user?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Thank you for your attention.

Here's the scenario : my activity consists in doing a simple simulation (a game played by two AIs one against another) several times, and keep doing it until the user presses a button. The data obtained is used to make the AIs better (I've already coded this part and it seems to be working).

I want the activity to display basic information like how many games have already been played.

I'm quite new to Android and Java development. I know I have to use a separate thread to do the simulations but I don't know how to handle it, as I've never used separate threads so far. What's bugging me is : does the new thread have access to public methods and variables of the class it's been started with ? If so, how ?

I've already read the documentation on threads on the official Android developers website.

Comment: You make a hook in the separate thread which checks if it should terminate. There are plenty ways to implement this, the easiest might be using a static variable, but I think your question is much too broad to give a good answer. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @popovitsj Well I tried to run the separate thread and to have a method that is started by a click on a button and that finishes the activity. But that doesn't seem right... Also, the whole separate thread is a while(true) loop, and that doesn't look like it's working either.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of a class is not tied to any Thread such as the main Thread that created it. 
A Thread created within a method in a class will have access to the private members of that class. It will have access to public members in whatever instances it is given by its creator or can get from a public method elsewhere (e.g. a static, or the Application Context).

So with multithreading you need to be careful as two threads can be accessing the same methods and variables at the same time, and you can never be sure which one will get there first. The safest way is to design it so that only one thread 'writes' to the variables and others just read.

Comment: Thank you! This looks helpful. I'll see if it resolves my problem.